# Display local date time in form while post utc(0) using ngxMatDatetimePicker in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, input, timezone, datetimepicker

I need to send a form in angular project that contains two [NgxMatDatetimePickerModule](https://h2qutc.github.io/angular-material-components/datetimepicker) based inputs (`startTime` and `endTime`), that should display the `LOCAL` time for User and post the `UTC(0)` to the server. While converting is not a problem using `momentjs` library, changing date to UTC right before post and making it LOCAL after the `subscribe`, changes the dates inside the input for a second and doesn't look pro, any ideas on how to do it proper and simple? (pipes? hidden inputs? sending time zone data to backend and solving it from there?)
Single input code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input class="datePicker startDate" name="startDate" matInput
        [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="startDate" placeholder="" formControlName="startDate"
        (dateChange)="changeDate('startDate', $event, reservationIndex)" [min]="minDate"
        [max]="maxDate" [readonly]="true" (click)="startDate.open()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #startDate [disableSecond]="true"></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
    <mat-error>
      ...
      <span>{{error.message}}</span>
</mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by setting `moment.tz.setDefault('Etc/UTC')` when i receive UTC in user config from API. It require to install `moment-timezone`.

Comment: can you please provide a stackbliz link to your solution. I have the same requirement